# SSD with Windows system has become "Unlocated" on System freezing for 30 minutes and rebooting manually after giving up waiting it unfreeze

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

So I have KINGSTON SUV400S37120G on which I have Window 11 installed.

The system was working totally fine.

I decided to enable System Restore because it was turned off:

[image]

The screenshot from another Windows System.
I was trying to enable it for system Disk "C" and another SSD "E" which didn't have any files at all. And then the OS started freezing, it become totally dead I could only control mouse cursor but nothing else was working. After 30-40 minutes I decided to press the reboot button on my PC, on first load I saw that SSD has gone from BIOS list. I turned off the PC, waited a couple of seconds and started it again, SSD appeared again in BIOS storage list but there were no any BOOT/EFIs detected any more to boot Windows.

Then I installed Windows on another SSD. Started Disk Management from it:
First I saw the following popup:

[image]

I pressed "cancel" so I would not write anything to that disk before I try to restore the DISK/DATA. Or mb I can just press "OK" and it will work fine again without data losing?

And now it's showing as (after pressing "cancel" button):

[image]

I tried to scan the data with EaseUS app and it seems detected that all files of the system disk are still there:

[image]

I already restored some files (most important) to another disk with this tool.

But now I'm trying to figure out how can I restore the disk with partition so I could boot it again without reinstalling the windows. Is it possible? cause it looks like all the data are still there but the disk is just detected as "unlocated". This tool can only copy files from disk to another disk but not restore the disk as it was before.

Comment: You probably can’t. What files are detected are likely the limits of what you’ll be able to recover. You replace the SSD immediately. If you want to use TestDisk on the drive, do it after and only after, you clone the SSD or recover all files you need

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I decided to fully recover all data using EaseUS tool from the partition to my external USB HDD.
And after that I will try "TestDisk Partition Recovery" option to see if it will be able to get it working again without formatting the disk and reinstalling Windows

Comment: Even if you get Windows to boot you’ll want to immediately clone the disk and replace it